# How to drop Countries that does not contain all indicators in a Panel Data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that is a Panel Data in long form:

```
    Country ISO3    Country Name    Indicator Id    Indicator   Subindicator Type   1980    1981    1982    1983    1984    ... 2015    2016    2017    2018    2019    2020    2021    2022    2023    2024
0   ABW Aruba   346 Gross national savings (% of GDP)   % of GDP    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... 15.466  17.221  17.044  18.203  19.872  19.228  18.487  17.654  16.826  15.808
1   ABW Aruba   347 Inflation, average consumer prices  Index   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... 118.354 117.303 116.728 120.796 122.460 124.789 127.376 130.091 132.896 135.769
2   ABW Aruba   352 Population (WEO)    Value   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... 109000.000  110000.000  111000.000  111000.000  112000.000  112000.000  112000.000  113000.000  113000.000  113000.000
3   ABW Aruba   2777    General government total expenditure(% of GDP)  % of GDP    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... 27.932  28.312  28.124  28.209  27.669  27.405  27.304  27.158  26.986  26.804
4   ABW Aruba   2779    General government net lending/borrowing(% of ...   % of GDP    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... -1.625  -1.640  -2.963  -1.937  -0.838  -0.575  -0.474  -0.328  -0.155  0.027
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2307    ZWE Zimbabwe    2777    General government total expenditure(% of GDP)  % of GDP    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... 20.525  23.372  22.484  14.079  10.862  14.246  14.673  16.146  16.569  16.708
2308    ZWE Zimbabwe    2779    General government net lending/borrowing(% of ...   % of GDP    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... -1.805  -6.539  -8.379  -3.766  -2.037  -2.545  -0.257  -0.417  -0.844  -0.984
2309    ZWE Zimbabwe    2783    General government primary net lending/borrowi...   % of GDP    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... -0.917  -5.929  -7.531  -3.075  -1.102  -1.308  0.622   0.329   -0.183  -0.369
2310    ZWE Zimbabwe    2787    General government gross debt(% of GDP) % of GDP    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... 41.806  54.164  52.866  29.781  20.987  20.490  20.068  19.554  18.611  17.682
2311    ZWE Zimbabwe    3092    Inflation, average consumer prices(Percent cha...   Percent change  NaN 5.556   0.59    -8.452  -1.857  ... -2.410  -1.558  0.907   10.607  73.425  9.366   3.700   3.000   3.000   3.000
```

The variable 'Indicator' and/or 'Indicator Id' column contain variables as 'Gross National Savigns', 'Inflation' and etc. I want to get only the countries from 'Country Name' column that have all indicators, this indicator are in 'Indicator' column and is presented in this list:

```
array(['Gross national savings (% of GDP)',
       'Inflation, average consumer prices', 'Population (WEO)',
       'General government total expenditure(% of GDP)',
       'General government net lending/borrowing(% of GDP)',
       'General government primary net lending/borrowing(% of GDP)',
       'General government gross debt(% of GDP)',
       'Inflation, average consumer prices(Percent change)',
       'Unemployment rate (% of total labor force) (WEO)',
       'Total investment (% of GDP)', 'Volume of imports (% change)',
       'Volume of exports (% change)',
       'General government structural balance(% of GDP)',
       'General government net debt(% of GDP)'], dtype=object)
```

For example if I have this dataframe for three countries, and only two meet all indicators, I want to drop the country that does not meet all indicator. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I has tried several forms to solve this issue. Please, help me.

Comment: "I want to get only the countries that contain all indicators", could you elaborate more? Try to edit your post to make your question more clear so that others can assist better.

Comment: Hi, Cavin, sorry for be unclear. I has edited my post. Thank you.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a specific issue here, just a list of requirements. Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
```

Created a sample data of my own to test the code.

```
x = StringIO("""Country,Indicator Id
ABW,"Inflation, average consumer prices(Percent change)"
ZBE,"General government total expenditure(% of GDP)"
CAR,"Volume of exports (% change)"
TAN,"Inflation, average consumer prices(Percent change)"
TAN,"General government total expenditure(% of GDP)"
ABW,"Volume of exports (% change)"
MAN,"General government total expenditure(% of GDP)"
FAN,"Inflation, average consumer prices(Percent change)"
GTR,"General government total expenditure(% of GDP)"
YUT,"Volume of exports (% change)"
TAN,"Volume of exports (% change)"
ABW,"General government total expenditure(% of GDP)"
""")

df = pd.read_csv(x, sep=',')
```

This gives the count of distinct indicators per country

```
df_count = df.groupby('Country', as_index=False).count()
```

Output:

```
  Country  Indicator Id
0     ABW             3
1     CAR             1
2     FAN             1
3     GTR             1
4     MAN             1
5     TAN             3
6     YUT             1
7     ZBE             1
```

Keep the countries with the max count (this is assuming that there exists atleast one country that has all the indicators).

```
countries_to_keep = df_count.loc[df_count['Indicator Id'] == df_count['Indicator Id'].max()]['Country'].tolist()

df = df.loc[df['Country'].isin(countries_to_keep)]
```

Final Output:

```
print(df)

   Country                                       Indicator Id
0      ABW  Inflation, average consumer prices(Percent cha...
3      TAN  Inflation, average consumer prices(Percent cha...
4      TAN     General government total expenditure(% of GDP)
5      ABW                       Volume of exports (% change)
10     TAN                       Volume of exports (% change)
11     ABW     General government total expenditure(% of GDP)
```